# Accessing Website running in Kubernetes Which is Running on Virtualbox from Host OS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, kubernetes

I am going through the Kubernetes quick start on Ubuntu 16.04 running in a VirtualBox VM on a Windows 10 host.

It has a NAT network adapter with a static IP address of 192.168.133.75.  I can ping this address from my host machine.

I have the "sock-shop" running my VM.  This is what I get when I run `kubectl describe svc front-end -n sock-shop`:

```
Name:               front-end
Namespace:          sock-shop
Labels:             name=front-end
Selector:           name=front-end
Type:               NodePort
IP:                 10.104.66.95
Port:               <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:           <unset> 30001/TCP
Endpoints:          10.32.0.18:8079
Session Affinity:   None
```

So when I go to `10.104.66.95` on my VM, I see the website and all is good, not so much on my host.

I have setup port forwarding on the network adapter as follows (I know IP addresses are options, I've also tried without them, but it didn't work):

[image: Port Forwarding]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the `NodePort` on your host, access the site via: `192.168.133.75:30001`

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport